# Marshal different sets of fields from a struct at runtime in Golang

Tags: go, unmarshalling

Lets say I have a struct like this (dummy example) :

```
type Animal struct {
   name string
   weight int
   isLandAnimal boolean
   Family
}

type Family struct {
   name string
   type string
}
```

Now what I want to achieve is something like this :

```
var a Animal = ....
bys, err := json.Marshal(a, []string{"name", "Family.name"})
```

and once printed **bys** should look like this :

```
{
   "name": "Lion"
   "family" : {
      "name" : "Felines"
   }
}
```

So I can pass a string slice that references which fields I want to actually get marshaled in the final string.

Does something like this exists in the standard library or in a third party one?

NOTE: This is what I could do based on another SO answer:
https://go.dev/play/p/XVb83zoXpmb
Will this bring troubles down the road?

Comment: Regarding your update to the question: No it won't bring "troubles", but like I said it's a mapping function :)

Comment: Instead of trying to only unmarshal part of the json, your example looks more like filtering existing json data.  Ever use `jq` to filter json data at command line?  https://github.com/itchyny/gojq Go implementation

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate the fields which let you specify how it should show up in json and if it needs to be omitted when empty. https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Marshal

Here is a working code. https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Marshal

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Animal struct {
    Name         string `json:"name,omitempty"`
    Weight       int    `json:"weight,omitempty"`
    IsLandAnimal bool   `json:"IsLandAnimal,omitempty"`
    Family       Family `json:"Family,omitempty"`
}

type Family struct {
    Name       string `json:"Name,omitempty"`
    Familytype string `json:"Familytype,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    a := Animal{Family: Family{Name: "Felines"}, Name: "Lion"}
    bys, _ := json.Marshal(a)
    fmt.Println(string(bys))
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking for is [struct field annotations for json.Marshal.](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Marshal) Basically go expects you to explicitly define the mapping from a `struct` to your export object, in this case `json`.

You need to ensure that the [fields in your struct are exported](https://golangbyexample.com/exported-unexported-fields-struct-go/), or basically start with a capital letter.

Next you can add a annotation to the end of the field to tell go what to look for when unmarshalling, or how to marshal that specific field into the file type format you're looking for.

For example:

This struct with exported members and annotations:

```golang
type Cookie struct {
   Name         string `json:"name"`
   Ingredients  int    `json:"ingredients"`
   MilkDunkTime int    `json:"milk_dunk_time"`
}
```

would export into this json:

```json
{
   "name": "",
   "ingredients: 0,
   "milk_dunk_time:" 0
}
```

---

[I've provided a playground link for your example above with some minor tweaks.](https://go.dev/play/p/00KHSNjsiml)

---

Comment: Please, take a look at my question again, I have included a snippet of what I mean. This is not really what I need.

Comment: Reflection is always a solution to this, but poses its own runtime issues. I think it is up to you as the author of whether or not you want to to deal with runtime issues, or write your helper functions for exporting the members in @Wolfgang's comment.